# Prove that Killing vector fields form Lie algebra.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I want to find the integral curves of $[X,Y]$, then maybe can use this to prove. Can anyone gives an answer ? Thanks.

Comment: Is your question the one in the title of this post? Or is it something else?

Comment: Yes,just the question in the title.

Comment: Just prove if $X$,$Y$ are both killing vector fields,then $[X,Y]$ is also killing vector field.Can anyone give some suggestions?Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

From the Jacobi identity and definition of Lie derivative it follows that $L_{[X,Y]} = L_X \circ L_Y - L_Y \circ L_X$.  Thus $L_{[X,Y]} g = 0$ if $L_Y g = 0$ and $L_X g = 0$.